# Parse incoming http post request java android

Tags: android, parsing, http-request

I am working on an Android web server.When i go to  localhost:8080 on the emulator browser, it serves a page/form  with a password field. On successful verification of the password, I would like to redirect the user to the success/failure page.What would be the best way to read the incoming http post request and parse the password field for verification?Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I have a handler for the url to which the form is submitted. The code for the handler is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentProducer;
import org.apache.http.entity.EntityTemplate;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandler;

import android.content.Context;

public class LoginHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {
private Context context = null;
public LoginHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void handle(final HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
        HttpContext httpcontext) throws HttpException, IOException {
       HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {
        public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
            String resp = null;
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8");
            if(validatePassword()==true){
             resp ="<html><head></head><body><h1>Home<h1><p>Success.</p></body></html>";
            }
            else{resp="<html><head></head><body><h1>Home<h1><p>Login Failed.</p></body></html>";}
            writer.write(resp);
            writer.flush();
        }


    });
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    response.setEntity(entity);

}
boolean validatePassword(){
boolean pass=false;
//parse request body here and check for the password if true return true/else false
 return pass;
 }


 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking around for ages I found the solution. Adding the following in the handle method does the trick.Thanks to the original poster
.http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/a-bare-minimum-web-server-for-android-platform

```
        if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request).getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
Log.v("RequestBody", EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8"));
entity.consumeContent();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I apologize if this isn't quite what you're asking, so if it's not, let me know.

You could use a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to return whether or not that password was verified as correct.

For example, if the password is correct, you could store the HTTP result as:

```
{"status":200,"confirmed":"true"}
```

Or "false" otherwise.

When you get back from the HTTP Post Request, you can store this result as a String, then make a `JSONObject` out of it.  For example:

```
// Send the URL to a postRequest function and return the result as a String
String output = makePostRequest(url);

// Parse the String as a JSONObject and receive whether or not the login was confirmed
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(output);
String confirmed = o.getString("confirmed");
if (confirmed.equals("true")) {
    // Password confirmed - redirect user to success page
} else {
    // Password incorrect - redirect user to failure page
}
```

**Note:** in case you need an idea of how to receive the response code from the post request, here's some sample code:

```
String output = {};

// Use bufferedreader and stringbuilder to build an output string (where conn is your HTTPUrlConnection object you used to make the post request    
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;

// Loop through response to build JSON String
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}

// Set output from response
output = sb.toString();
```

And now `output` is the String you can turn into a JSONObject.

Does any of this help?

---

**Edit:**
Okay, so the String you will be getting will be in the format of `{"password":"somepassword"}`.  To parse this, try this out:

```
String s = /* the string in the format {"password":"somepassword"} */
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(s);
String password = o.getString("password");
if (password.equals(random_password_at_beginning_of_webservice) {
    // Password confirmed - redirect user to success page
} else {
    // Password incorrect - redirect user to failure page
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back.Well it is a single user app without a database.When the android service is started it displays a password.I would like to verify if it is the same user requesting for  the service.I haven't used JSON before but looks like it is a viable option provided there is a parser for JSON on android.

Comment: `getString` returns String, not `boolean`

Comment: My apologies, that is fixed :).

Comment: @Mike Gates I took some time to have a look at JSON.The posted data json stucture should be like {"password":"somepassword"}.The server is the android phone  and the form is posted to localhost on the android phone.So I would like to parse the above string in json format and check for the password field against the random password generated on start of the WebServerService on the android phone.Hope I made myself clear.If you would like some more information please let me know.Thanks

Comment: I posted an edit to my answer.  See if that helps/is what you're asking for.  If it is not, I may need a bit more of an explanation of what part it is exactly you'd like help with.

Comment: @Mike Gates I appreciate your response but, I would like to parse the http request itself which is very tricky as I am not allowed to use any server side language.I know that request.getParameter("parametername") does the job when I use servlet api.Is there anything similar that I can use on android.I  am using org.apache.http on android side to create my own webserver.Hope that helps.